# How to copy text side by side in Npp or Sublime text?

Tags: text-editors, text-editing

I have to 2 text files . First is

```
A
B
C
D
```

Second is

```
1
2
3
4
```

How do I copy both file contents side by side like this in Notepad++ or Sublime Text . If these both don't support this then please suggest a editor which does .

```
A1
B2
C3
D4
```

Answer (score 4):

In notepad++ you can hold down alt+shift then select an entire column of text. So in the example above,

1. highlight 1-4 lines using the alt+shift and mouse,
2. ctrl+c to copy it to the clipboard
3. put cursor at the A and ctrl+v to paste.

(assuming windows hotkeys)

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 2 on Windows, you highlight the lines you want to copy and use Ctrl+C to copy them. You then put your cursor at the start of where you want to paste them and use Ctrl+Alt+Down to add another cursor on the next line, and repeat until you have a cursor on each line (alternatively, Ctrl+click where you want each cursor; if you end up with some cursors not on the beginning or end of the line, hit Home or End as appropriate, which will put all cursors on the beginning/end of their line). You then use Ctrl+V to paste; if you have as many lines on the clipboard as cursors, it will paste one line per cursor.

Answer (score 0):

In **SynWrite** app: select vertical block (using Alt+mouse select) in 1st file, select vertical block in 2nd file, now you can copy each block to clipbd, and paste into 3rd empty file: paste 2nd block just righter than 1st block.